# Selenium Hub requests capabilities do not match with browser node capabilities

Tags: selenium, docker, kubernetes, selenium-grid, minikube

I'm trying to point some tests at a selenium hub that I have set up and I'm coming across some possible issues with the configuration/capabilities of the browsers.

When I look at the logs for the Hub Pod that I have set up in minikube, I see the following message (multiple times, the test script retries a few times then gives up and shows a fail status)

```
16:26:14.221 INFO - Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities [{loggingPrefs=org.openqa.selenium.logging.LoggingPreferences@5a4fa56e, timeZone=Greenwich, unhandledPromptBehavior=ignore, version=47, platform=ANY, public=share, acceptSslCerts=true, name=dockerdev : Web UI Smoke test, browserName=firefox, idle-timeout=90, platformName=ANY, maxDuration=1800, firefox_profile=UEsDBBQACAgIAEeDM0sAAAAAAAAAA..., unexpectedAlertBehaviour=ignore}]
16:26:14.222 INFO - Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities [{loggingPrefs=org.openqa.selenium.logging.LoggingPreferences@4790a536, timeZone=Greenwich, unhandledPromptBehavior=ignore, version=47, platform=ANY, public=share, acceptSslCerts=true, name=dockerdev : Web UI Smoke test, browserName=firefox, idle-timeout=90, platformName=ANY, maxDuration=1800, firefox_profile=UEsDBBQACAgIAEeDM0sAAAAAAAAAA..., unexpectedAlertBehaviour=ignore}]
org.openqa.grid.common.exception.CapabilityNotPresentOnTheGridException: cannot find : Capabilities [{loggingPrefs=org.openqa.selenium.logging.LoggingPreferences@4790a536, timeZone=Greenwich, unhandledPromptBehavior=ignore, version=47, platform=ANY, public=share, acceptSslCerts=true, name=dockerdev : Web UI Smoke test, browserName=firefox, idle-timeout=90, platformName=ANY, maxDuration=1800, firefox_profile=UEsDBBQACAgIAEeDM0sAAAAAAAAAA..., unexpectedAlertBehaviour=ignore}]
    at org.openqa.grid.internal.ProxySet.verifyAbilityToHandleDesiredCapabilities(ProxySet.java:180)
    at org.openqa.grid.internal.Registry.addNewSessionRequest(Registry.java:224)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.process(RequestHandler.java:103)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.process(DriverServlet.java:84)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:317)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.Invocable.invokePreferred(Invocable.java:128)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.Invocable$InvocableExecutor.invoke(Invocable.java:222)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:294)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:199)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

When I look at the configuration for one of my firefox pods I see the following:

```
Capabilities [{seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, acceptSslCerts=true, screen-resolution=1900x1880, tz=Greenwich, browserName=firefox, maxInstances=1, screenResolution=1900x1880, resolution=1900x1880, version=55.0.3, platform=LINUX}]
```

I think perhaps versioning might be my issue as the the firefox pod is 55.0.3 and the requested capability shows 47, but I'm not sure what else could be an issue. What should I be looking into for more details about my problem?

For reference my hub looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFh73.png)

Comment: can you explain how did you spin up hub and how did you try to register a node to it?

Comment: Can you show us the test code? It seems the test is specifically requesting for version 47.

Comment: Yes that was the issue, the test was using an older version. I updated the version to match the configured browsers version.